# How to get multiple rows in subsonic

Tags: subsonic

I am using the following

Product objProduct = new Product("active_flag","true");

This one will result multiple row, how can I access the multple rows? ObjProduct will have only one row?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using 2.1 or above you can do the following:

```
ProductCollection products = DB.Select().From(Product.Schema)
  .Where(Product.Columns.active_flag).IsEqualTo(true)
  .ExecuteAsCollection<ProductCollection>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way...

```
ProductCollection products = new ProductCollection()
   .Where(Product.Columns.active_flag, true)
   .Load();
```